# How can I install C compiler properly for Python package installation for Windows?

Tags: python, c, windows, virtualenv

I believe I don't have my C compiler properly installed.  I'm trying to install some Python 2.7 packages on my Windows 8 machine.  I keep receiving the following error:

> RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program.

Python is installed properly and has been working well regularly.  I've been using the `virutalenv` package and working in a virtual environment.  I've then tried installing Cygwin, MinGW, and MS Visual Studios 2012, none of which seem to work in the `virtualenv`.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be great.

Thank you,
Jimmy

Comment: You don't want to install anything but python packages within a virtualenv. So deactivate your virtualenv and install Cygwin and see my list of gcc tools you need to install in Cygwin to have yourself a working compiler/linker to avoid compile errors like the one you describe above.

Comment: If you are expecting a `cygwin` installation to help, you have to do you python package installation inside of the cygwin environment, most likely from a cygwin command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, despite installing gcc and mingw-gcc under CygWin, per [scipy recommendations](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/windows.html#id2). But this might get you further down the track:

```
setup-x86_64.exe -q -n -N -d -R 'C:\cygwin64' -s 'http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/x86_64/release/' -l 'C:\Users\$USER\Downloads' -P git,wget,curl,python,gcc-core,mingw-gcc
```

Eventually I just had to mousily install all the Cygwin packages that came up in the search for "gcc". I only selected those under the "dev" category rather than "debug" and `pip install numpy` (which compiles and links a lot of C packages) worked fine.  Here's [my list of Cygwin packages](https://gist.github.com/hobsonlane/6802139).

I'm on Windows 7 (when I can't avoid it), but not Win 8.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the following packages and it seems to work:

- gcc-core
- make
- python-devel

Hope this would work for you as well.

P.S.: Used apt-cyg to do the install. https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg